# Installing 14.04.2 on eeepc 1015PE

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, error-handling

Good morning,

I am having trouble installing Trusty Tahr on my netbook.

I am attempting to achieve a dual boot configuration, my netbook came with windows 7 starter and so I am attempting to follow the instructions posted on the [ubuntu website](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot#Install_Ubuntu) but receive the same error each time.

The instructions allude to the ability to partition your drive during the installation, however I never get to that option. I am able to boot from a live USB and the installation begins (cycles through text and then i see the xubuntu screen and scrolling circle). I then receive an error titled "Failed to set new theme" and in the body it mentions something about the hard drive being full.

Why am I experiencing this error, and how to I circumvent it to get the dual boot configuration I want?

PC Specs:
1.66MhZ intel atom processor
2GB RAM
150GB harddrive (80GB free, intend to allot 60GB to Ubuntu...if I can get there).

Comment: I have (almost ---a 1005PE) the same laptop working ok. You have to resize the disk in *windows* --- reduce your disk form 150 to 80 and leave the remaining space unallocated.  Even if it's free, if the disk is visible to windows, Ubuntu will not touch it (unless you choose manual partitioning, but resizing a windows drive in anything different from windows is calling for trouble). Anyway, **backup first!**

Comment: I attempted to resize the C: partition, only to find that I cannot shrink it by more than 400MB (to effectively only allow 400MB for ubuntu). Ubuntu clearly states (in several other websites https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowtoResizeWindowsPartitions#Windows_Vista_and_Windows_7) that the installer can do that for you, and that there is no need to do this before installing Ubuntu

Comment: Upon booting from the USB, I am supposed to be prompted with the Ubuntu installation steps, but I receive that error before any other propts show up

Comment: This is because the installer sees the same 400M free space that windows sees. Defragment and retry. And resizing from the installer a live windows file system works... But sometimes it doesn't, if you can do it in windows its safer.

Comment: Okay, did a factory restore which freed up a lot of HDD space...now I am receiving a new error...or lack thereof. Upon booting from my Live USB, it just sits on a black screen. No longer getting the hard drive error. I have followed advice regarding installation options (http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it) and none of these seem to work...any suggestions?

Comment: Sorry, no idea --- my 1005PE works ok with just the `acpi_osi=Linux` kernel option --- but I have installed it ages ago and kept upgrading. Sorry again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure the cause of the issue, but I was able to work around it by using an older installation (14.04.1) and then upgrade that way...not sure why that worked. Had to enter the setup menu (push the down arrow as soon as you select the boot to USB option and a small white icon appears at the bottom) and then disable 2 options (hit english and then F6 to enter the options menu, turn off the nomodset and no lapic)